# my jquery code doesnot work in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My jquery code doesnot work in bootstrap. i have some columns and i want to put submission form within specific column but when i use form tag my jquery wont work.

```
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col-1">
            <button id="btn">hide me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col-2">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col-4">

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $("#row1").slideUp("slow");
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use preventDefault() as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#row1").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

When you are putting the `form` tag and there is a `button` tag inside it, the default action is to submit the form. So you need to prevent that first using `preventDefault()`.

Please let me know if it solved the issue or not.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Please accept the answer by clicking the 'Tick' under the vote counter arrows.

Comment: Done. anything else?

Comment: Thank you, nothing else friend :)